# Prove that there are infinitely many choices of an embedded $P_i$-primary ideal in a minimal primary decomposition.

Tags: commutative-algebra, primary-decomposition

I've started to study about minimal primary decompositions and have this problem:

> Let $I$ be a proper ideal of a commutative Noetherian ring $R$, and let $I=Q_1\cap\cdots\cap Q_n$ with $\sqrt{Q_i}=P_i$ $(i=1,...,n$) be a minimal primary decomposition of $I$. Suppose that $P_i$ is an embedded prime ideal of $I$.
>
> Prove that there are infinitely many different choices of an alternative $P_i$-primary ideal of $R$ which can be substituted for $Q_i$ in the above decomposition so that the result is still a minimal primary decomposition of $I$.

(This is Ex. 8.36 in *Steps in Commutative Algebra* by R.Y.Sharp.)

I have no idea to showing "infinitely many", thank for your help.

Comment: Hint. Use exercises 8.33, 8.34 and 8.35.

Comment: i knew that, but find no way :| can you expland more?

Comment: Expand on what? On how to use the previous exercises in order to solve this one?

Comment: yes, please tell me more about it.